# android 2.x系でコマンドラインからスクリーンショットを撮影する方法

Tags: android

android 2系で、コマンドラインからマウス操作をせずにスクリーンショットを撮影する方法はありますでしょうか。
4.x系では adb shell screencap -p "/sdcard/ss.png" とやってpullすれば画像が取得出来たのですが、2系では同コマンドがそもそも無い模様です。

ADBのddmsのGUIからならスクリーンショットの表示＆保存が出来るのですが、マウス操作が必須でどうにも使い勝手が悪いです。
DDMSから取れるのであれば技術的には可能だと思うのですが・・・

端末はGalaxy S(2.3.6)、SO-01B(2.1-update1)ですが、2系全般の方法を教えて頂きたいです。
4.4からscreencapをadb pullしてギャラクシーSにadb pullしてchmodして実行してみたのですが、Segmentation faultと言われて終わってしまいました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決しました
Android Screen Monitor http://adakoda.github.io/android-screen-monitor/
Android Screen Monitor - adakoda http://www.adakoda.com/adakoda/android/asm/
上記ソフトで2.x系のスクリーンショットが取得出来るのですが、オープンソースなのでコマンドラインの処理を受け付ける処理を追加する事が出来ました。
クラスの構造が綺麗だったのでデバイス＆出力ファイル名決め打ちならコピペで出来るレベルだと思います。

失礼しました。クローズさせて頂きます